# vue3 props passed to child component are undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Im struggling with passing data to my child component.

On level of parent componenet, I'm doing nested axios call to retrieve the data. Then I pass this data to my child component. Data is correct, but child component sees it as undefined.

It looks like the child component is rendered before the actual call is finished.

parent:

```
<template>
    <User_Menu v-if="user_info" :user="user_info" :user_tickets="user_tickets"/>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import User_Menu from "@/components/User/User_Menu.vue"
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { ref, reactive, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { UserQrInstance } from '@/interfaces/user';
import { UserTickets } from '../interfaces/tickets';
import { post_call, get_call} from "@/api"
import { error_notification } from "@/error_notifications"

const route = useRoute()
const user_id = ref(0)

const user_info = reactive({} as UserQrInstance)
const user_tickets = reactive([] as UserTickets)

const get_user_tickets = async (qr: string) => {
    try
    {   
        const response = await post_call('tickets/get_tickets', {qr_code: qr})
        Object.assign(user_tickets, response.data)
    }
    catch (e){
        error_notification(e)
    }
}

const get_user = async () => {
    try
    {   
        const response = await get_call(`users/find_user/${user_id.value}`)
        Object.assign(user_info, response.data)
        await get_user_tickets(response.data.qr_code)
    }
    catch (e){
        error_notification(e)
    }
}

onMounted(() => {
    user_id.value = route.params.id
    get_user()
})
</script>
```

child:

```
<template>
  {{props.user}}
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

const props = defineProps<{user: Ref<UserQrInstance>, user_tickets: Ref<UserTickets>}>()

console.log(props.user) -> ok
console.log(props.user.name) -> undefined

</script>
```

How can I make it working? Some delay or something?

Comment: v-if="user_info" - this is a mistake, it's always defined, use a ref instead of empty object

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you set the initial value of `user_info`  to an empty object and then check it like this `v-if="user_info"` in your template, the empty array return `true` in this situation, and actually your condition is always true.

you have two options:
1- you can define your initial value like this:
`const user_info = reactive<UserQrInstance>()`
now the initial value is set to undefined so you get `false` when you check it in `v-if`

2- you can check on the required value in your data in `v-if`, here is an example:
we suppose that you have a required id in your data:

```
<User_Menu v-if="user_info[0]?.id" :user="user_info" :user_tickets="user_tickets"/>
```

now if `user_info` has data in it, it must have an `id` and you check the first one so just when having data in it, it passes the `v-if`